# PHP extract and parse _ basic question

Tags: php, parsing, ip, extract

I have some files (about 500 files) with NO extension.
But I managed to view its contents , it has some weird tags and stuff.

I need to extract all  IP addreesses from it.. For ex in line 2 there is always an IP address like this ... `(71.129.195.163)`

Also, there are some html tags like < a href = "http://www.xyz.com"  > in a lot of lines.
I need to get this domain name from it , like  `xyz.com`.

could someone assist this php newbie? i know to get the entire file as a string and all tht.. but since php is powerful, I am looking for a sweet and simple way to achieve this .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are great for this.

To find all IPs in a file:

```
$ipPattern = '/(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}/';

$ips = array();
preg_match_all($ipPattern, $fileContents, $ips);
$ips = $ips[0];
```

To find all links:

```
$linkPattern = '/href(\s+)?\=(\s+)?[\'"](.+?)[\'"]/';

$links = array();
preg_match($linkPattern, $fileContents, $links);

$link = $links[3];
```

The file content is assumed to be in $fileContents.
Run this code for every file.
If you need to collect all IPs and domains than you can merge them into big arrays:

```
$allIps = array();
$allLinks = array();

// after each run of the above code do:
$allIps = array_merge($allIps, $ips);
$allLinks[] = $link;
```

Comment: Hi, The links array is empty for the code that you wrote ... nice code btw... there are multiple a href lines and it's enough if I only read the first occurrence as it has the domain name ... thx for your help . how do i modify that ...  "? i am using foreach ($ips as $key => $a1) { echo $a1; }  .. but i am only gettin "array" displayed.. so are these 2 dimensional arrays ?!

Comment: q2 : Also would like to know how  $linkPattern = '/href\w?\=\w?[\'"]{1}(.+?)[\'"]{1}/';
   and $ipPattern = '/(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}/';
 work ?

Comment: when you get an output like array you can dump the array in a readable format to understand the data: var_dump($a1); to get the ip you will probably need to do $ip = $a1[1];

Comment: Sooo, I have fixed my code. There was an error in the regular expression for links, but it should work now. I also adapted to find only one domain per file. Mind how I changed preg_match_all to preg_match! The two patterns are REGULAR EXPRESSIONS. Google for it to find out more, they are very useful

Comment: Help me modify $linkpattern  , the patterns are changing.. some files have HREF in caps .. some have spaces between characters.. Also, I only need to display the domain names till  " .com  "  and not further.. i.e m not interested in post methods ...  please help a lil more , Thanks a lot ...

Comment: and after making it ~preg_match ~ , am getting an error , like undefined offset 3 ... with _all, I am getting some correct domains, and some of their extensions that i don't need... like xyz.com/mmmmn.aspx   , is this solvable.. thanks for your time/

Comment: Can u just please explain this alone ?? '/href(\s+)?\=(\s+)?[\'"](.+?)[\'"]/';